# How to arrange user input checkboxes (or other user inputs) neatly in a grid pattern?

Tags: r, shiny

In the below MWE code I'd like to find a neat, organised way to arrange user checkbox inputs. The `fluidRows` and `columns` that I use are hard to work with and present cleanly. In the full App this MWE derives from, there are 12 user checkboxes so I need to find a clean way to arrange them and place them close together. As you can see in the below image and when running the code, the buttons do not line up in the rows correctly, the rows are too tall, gridlines would be helpful, etc.

The below code only uses "Show" and "Hide" checkboxes for the sake of clarity.

MWE code:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

firstInput <- function(inputId){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(5), 1, 1, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),NULL)),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

secondInput <- function(inputId,x){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(x), 1, 1, dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),NULL)),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Model"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("panel"),
        hidden(uiOutput("secondInput"))),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  input1      <- reactive(input$input1)
  input2      <- reactive(input$input2)
  
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      useShinyjs(),
      firstInput("input1"),
      strong(helpText("Generate curves (Y|X):")),
      
      div(style = "font-size: 14px; padding: 0px; margin-top:0em",
        fluidRow(
          fluidRow(
            column(5,),
            column(2,helpText("Show"),align="center"),
            column(2,helpText("Hide"),align="center"),
            column(2,helpText("Reset"),align="center")
          ),
          div(style = "font-size: 14px; padding: 0px; margin-top:0em",  
            fluidRow(
              column(5, helpText("1st input"),offset = 1),
              column(2, checkboxInput('show', NULL, value = FALSE, width = NULL)),
              column(2, checkboxInput('hide', NULL, value = FALSE, width = NULL)),
              column(2,)
            )
          ),
          div(style = "font-size: 14px; padding: 0px; margin-top:0em",  
            fluidRow(
              column(5,helpText("2nd input"),offset = 1),
              column(2,),
              column(2,),
              column(2,)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input1())
    secondInput("input2",input$input1[1,1])
  })
  
  outputOptions(output, "secondInput", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input2())
    plot(rep(input2(),times=5))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    shinyjs::show("secondInput")
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "hide", value = FALSE)
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$hide,{
    shinyjs::hide("secondInput")
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "show", value = FALSE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Don’t put `rm(list = ls())` in your R code, it’s an [anti-pattern](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/#whats-wrong-with-rmlist-ls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put these inputs in a table:

```
library(shiny)

f <- function(action, i){
  as.character(
    checkboxInput(paste0(action, i), label = NULL)
  )
}

actions <- c("shovv", "hide", "reset")
tbl <- t(outer(actions, c(1,2), FUN = Vectorize(f)))
colnames(tbl) <- c("Shovv", "Hide", "Reset")
rownames(tbl) <- c("1st input", "2nd input")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  tableOutput("checkboxes")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output[["checkboxes"]] <- renderTable({
    tbl
  }, 
  rownames = TRUE, align = "c",
  sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
  )
  
  observe({
    print(input[["hide1"]])
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

With a bit of CSS, it renders well in the sidebar:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "td .checkbox {margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
       td .form-group {margin-bottom: 0;}"
    ))
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tableOutput("checkboxes")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)
```

[image]